# What's the meaning of "Ma" when a husband addresses his wife?

Tags: nouns, names, historical-change, cinema

I know ["Ma"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ma) is the shortened form of Mother.
Yesterday I saw a classic movie named `"The Grapes of Wrath"` by John Ford in 1940.
In the movie the father of the family calls his wife ["Ma"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ma) and she calls him "Pa".
I'm wondering what's behind this calling?Is this generational, or regional?

Supposedly, Ford was following the script from Steinbeck.

Comment: Well, he's a father - maybe there's something to be said for the fact that his kids surely call her "Ma" as well...

Comment: Can you please post the sentence where the term is used.

Comment: “Ma” is the same as “Mom,” which is short for Mother. The pronunciation is characteristic of some American dialects at some time periods. Some men call their wives by the terms they want their children to use for her.

Comment: It used to make a sort of sense when people had a lot of children but it was already dated in the 1930s. It meant that everyone in the family only had one name but only less educated people used to do it much. British working class people, particularly in parts of northern England, used to do it as well but they tended to use 'father' and 'mother'. However the use of 'Mam' to refer to a man's wife was still common in Lincolnshire in the 1970s. The use of it in the book and film was part of the characterisation of the man and woman.

Comment: More recently than the 30s it's quite common for parents to try and refer to each other as mum/mummy/ma and dad/pop/daddy (or whatever) in front of the children, so the children use these terms and don't call parents by their first names (which as the Simpsons shows us is a great sin only done by the most disobedient children). I can imagine this would become a habit, although you don't describe the scene and if children are present.

Comment: Ma and Pa Joad are known by those two nicknames.  It was a fairly common practice in that time and place.

Comment: Ronald Reagan referred to Nancy as "Mommy" many times in public...

Comment: There is the element of a very interesting question here...I have voted to re-open. I think that at some point in recent (last 200 years) history this was considered common usage...so the better question might be when and why. I have edited to reflect that idea. If you are unhappy with the changes you can always roll-back or contribute some others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a bit out-dated, but not a surprising usage.  When kids are small and just learning to speak, the first words they usually learn are the "names" of their parents.  This is typically "Mama" and "Dada", "Ma" and "Pa", "Mommy" and "Daddy", etc.

When talking to the kids the parents will often refer to each other with those names -- "Go ask Mommy to give you some water."

Thus parents get in the habit of using these names, and will tend to use them even when kids are not being spoken to, or even present.  Most commonly, in more modern societies, this practice will abate as the kids grow up, but in a few families the usage may continue even into old age.

Comment: +1 Yes...this is a good explanation. In my house, even though the "Baby" is now 18 years old, we still all call each other by "baby" names. Also see; _Dirty Dancing_ for an older example.

Comment: Hi Hotlicks. If the question is worth an answer, it is also worthy of an upvote...and Re-Open...

Comment: I came here to answer this. It'd be interesting to know if people speaking other languages do this.